# Flash AS3 Audio Player seems to just stop working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, media-player

So far my code stops the sound but once it has stopped the sound no longer works. I don't see any errors reported.

It is as if the event listener no longer listens...

```
stop();
var soundClip:Sound = new Sound();
var sndChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var soundClipCompleted = false;
var isPlaying = false;
soundClip.load(new URLRequest("tune.mp3"));
soundClip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete,false,0,true);
function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
    sndChannel=soundClip.play();
    soundClipCompleted=true;
    isPlaying = true;
    Action_BtnPlay.gotoAndStop(2);
}
Action_BtnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, playBtn);
function playBtn (evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if(isPlaying && soundClipCompleted){
        sndChannel.stop();
        Action_BtnPlay.gotoAndStop(1);
    }else{
        sndChannel = soundClip.play();
        Action_BtnPlay.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stop();
var soundClip:Sound = new Sound();
var sndChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var soundClipCompleted = false;
var isPlaying = false;
soundClip.load(new URLRequest("tune.mp3"));
soundClip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete,false,0,true);
function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
sndChannel=soundClip.play();
soundClipCompleted=true;
isPlaying = true;
Action_BtnPlay.gotoAndStop(2);
}
Action_BtnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, playBtn);
function playBtn (evt:MouseEvent):void {
if(isPlaying && soundClipCompleted){
    sndChannel.stop();
    Action_BtnPlay.gotoAndStop(1);
    isPlaying=false;
    soundClipCompleted=false;
}else{
    sndChannel = soundClip.play();
    Action_BtnPlay.gotoAndStop(2);
  }
 }
```

You should set isPlaying and soundClipCompleted variable false.

Comment: @WebOD-Bradley: if your problem is solved than u can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You set both `isPlaying` and `soundClipCompleted` to `true` when the Sound first dispatches a COMPLETE event, so after that, the if statement in your `playBtn` handler will always evaluate to `true` and stop the sound.